# How to import tkinter msgbox without import normal tkinter window

Tags: python, tkinter, messagebox

This is my code to make a tkinter msgbox:

```
import tkinter.messagebox    # just imported tkinter.messagebox - right???
def warning():
    tkinter.messagebox.showwarning("Warning", "A Warning-box!")  # simply  
warning()       # executes warning()
```

All right - this is my code. When I am running the Programm there is this result:
[image]

The normal tkinter window is also imported. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Comment: If you're looking to just have the message box you can simply create your own message box with the TK window

Comment: `Try: your app Except,e : if module_error  : import required_module; re_run_your function`

Comment: Most awfull things is `import module; use_and_delete_module; again... again...` did you have any idea about of length of indexess ! İmport module staticaly or part of module..

Comment: Actionally: No...